# Logstash Multiline filter

Tags: multiline, logstash

We have some files that are written out to our web servers whenever we have php errors.  Each error has it's own file, but there are always multiple lines in each file.  The files always start with the text "Excepton:".  Is there a way to easily just say, "take the whole file as a log event?"  See example below:

```
Exception: ABC_Exception_Domain -- Message: There is no valid performance dimension for the given nodeRootId.
Error Date and Time:
    Date: September 25, 2014
    Time: 10:38:15
    Timestamp: 1411659495
    PersonId: 3947680
    ProcessId: 18055
    Memory Usage: 18194784
    Machine Id:...
```

and here is my configuration file that I am using to test output:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "stack_trace"
    path => [ "/root/20[1-9][0-9]*" ]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  multiline {
    type => "stack_trace"
    pattern => "^Exception.*$"
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
  }
}
output {
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

I have also tried this to use the last line as the log delimiter:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "stack_trace"
    path => [ "/root/20[1-9][0-9]*" ]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  multiline {
    type => "stack_trace"
    pattern => "^#[0-9]{1,3} \{main\}.*$"
    negate => true
    what => "previous"
  }
}
output {
   stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
   }
}
```

The only way I ever get any results is if I update the files manually and add another Exception or main line.

Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if I can provide anymore information.
Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `$` anchor from your filter?  Normally it specifically matches end-of-line, not end-of-file.

Comment: Removing the $ produces the same behaviour.  It's very strange and now I think it may have more to do with the log files than my logstash setup. It seems the last line of my logs don't have a end of line 0A, but if I open them up in vi and write quit it puts a 0A in and logstash will process them.  This is what the last line looks like: #9 {main}

Comment: Any idea on how to get this to work without a line feed on the last line of the log file?

Comment: Any update on this? @cdlaforc can you please post the solution if you found one?

Comment: Hey @AlexG, I think what ended up fixing it was our developers added a blank line between each distinct error and we made our filter look like this:  
 `multiline {  
      pattern => "^$"  
      negate => true  
      what => previous  
    }`

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.