# How to configure Logstash to use one event for one file (for parsing mails)?

Tags: email, parsing, logstash, imap, elastic-stack

Target: analyze big set of emails stored in files.
I have used **offlineimap** tool to download emails to local files.

I am familiar with ELK a bit however not sure how to configure Logstash properly to store one event per one file.

I have not tried multiline plugin yet because I do not have complete set of rules for starting/ending files. I just want to parse all files and store one event per one file regardless of how it starts/ends.

NOTE: could not use Logstash **imap** plugin because it fetches and stores only new emails, it does not load all mails from the server.

Similar question for different use case: [Logstash Multiline filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535907/logstash-multiline-filter)
unfortunately does not have any answer for more than couple years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was suggested in comments at [Logstash Multiline filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535907/logstash-multiline-filter) and it worked. Basically I had to add some string to end of all files and then use multiline plugin.

Created shell script to update all files with extra line:

```
for file in **/**/*; do
  echo 'ENDOFMAILFILE' >> "$file"
done
```

after that I have used multiline plugin in logstash

```
input {
  file {
    type => "logmail"
    path => [ "/var/log/mail/**/*" ]
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^ENDOFMAILFILE$"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
```